# How to get VMWARE ESX 3i Image from infrastructure client using script

Tags: vmware, esx

I've download the SDK to try to copy the image to my PC from the server but no cmdlet for copy just get info moving etc

any help?

Comment: Removed `3i` tag. Should it be `esx-3i`?

Answer (score 1):

You may have problems running the image locally, you'll want to use VMWare converter to transfer the image in a format you can use (in VMWare server etc).

Otherwise, use vifs in the remote cli: http://www.vmware.com/pdf/vi3_35/esx_3/r35u2/vi3_35_25_u2_rcli.pdf